# Set data in Javascript using Java Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I need to integrate Java and Javascript using Nashorn. I have data that exists in the Java context, and I need to pass it to the Javascript context.

In Java, I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {

    private List<String> list;

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
          this.list = list;
    }

    public String getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    //... getters and setters
}
```

I first instantiate in Java `MyClass javaObj = new MyClass();` and then fill data in the `list` with the `setList` method.

Now, I need to use the data inside the Javascript. I can instantiate `MyClass` using Nashorn, but since it's a different instance than the one that has the data I cannot use it.

In Javascript:

```
var jsClass = Java.type('MyClass'); 
var jsObj = new jsClass();
var jsObj = //.. fill out jsObj using data in the object instantiated in Java
```

How to assign to `jsObj` the data present in `javaObj`?